# Trouble writing to a workbook using ruby spreadsheet gem from CSV file

Tags: ruby, excel, csv, spreadsheet

I am currently new to Ruby and am having a hard time writing to an excel file.

I want to parse through a CSV file, extract data where the 'food' column in the csv file = butter and put the rows where 'food' column = butter into a new excel workbook. I can write the data that contains butter in the 'food' column just fine into a CSV file but am having trouble writing it to a workbook (excel format).

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'csv'
require 'spreadsheet'

csv_fname = 'commissions.csv'

options = { headers: :first_row }

food_type = { 'food' => 'butter'}

food_type_match = nil

CSV.open(csv_fname, 'r', options) do |csv|
  food_type_match = csv.find_all do |row|
    Hash[row].select { |k,v| food_type[k] } == food_type
  end
end

#writing the 'butter' data to a CSV file
#CSV.open('butter.csv', 'w') do |csv_object|
# food_type_match.each do |row_array|
#   csv_object << row_array
# end
#end

book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
sheet1 = book.create_worksheet

food_type_match.each do |csv|
  csv.each_with_index do |row, i|
    sheet1.row(i).replace(row)
  end
end
```

The spreadsheet generates but comes out blank. I have searched through numerous topics on ruby spreadsheet but I cannot get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Completely** 
What if you try this:

```
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
sheet1 = book.create_worksheet

food_type_match.each do |csv|
  csv.each_with_index do |row, i|
    sheet1.insert_row(i,row)
  end
end
book.write('/path_to_output_location/book.xls')
```

Also where does this output to? I cannot see a give path for this so I would think that is the issue but you say it generates? I added the write line because the code states this for `#write`

> Write this Workbook to a File, IO Stream or Writer Object. The latter will
>    make more sense once there are more than just an Excel-Writer available.

Like I said I am completely unfamiliar with this gem and the documentation is terrible with `axslx` it would be something like this

```
package = Axlsx::Package.new
book = package.workbook
book.add_worksheet do |sheet|
  food_type_match.each do |csv|
    sheet.add_row csv
  end
end
package.serialize('/path_to_output_location/book.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried making this adjustment but received 'warning: this causes ArgumentError in the next release 'warning: wrong element type String at 2460(expected array). The #select in its current format will extract the data I am trying to retrieve. If I comment out the section from #book down and only use 'puts food_type_match' -- it will display all rows that match 'butter' in the 'food' column. I have the extracted data I need in the 'food_type_match' variable but cannot get it to save to the excel workbook.

Comment: @ScottyBrown I am not very familiar with the spreadsheet gem I will look at the docs but I use the `axlsx` gem quite a bit. It is very easy to use and thoroughly documented.

Comment: Okay great and thank you for the help - I am going to look through the axlsx documentation. I am in no way married to using the spreadsheet gem and will happily switch to axlsx if I am to solve the issue.

Comment: @ScottyBrown I have added what I think might help with `spreadsheet` and also an example of the same in `axlsx`

Comment: My mistake - I forgot to add in 'book.write(\path_to_output\book.xls' -- I tried both sets of code and while they do populate the spreadsheet with the information, the formatting is a bit strange. The axlsx will populate the data but will move across columns instead of down rows. For example, populates A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, instead of A1,A2,A3 etc.. I really appreciate the help. I will review the documentation further and see if I can adjust the formatting.

Comment: `axlsx` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try `write_xlsx` gem. Here is my simple `csvtoxlsx.rb` script to combine `*.csv` in a `folder` to a `single.xlsx`:

```
require "csv"
require "write_xlsx"

def csvtoxls(csv, xlsx)

    count = 0

    workbook = WriteXLSX.new(xlsx)

    Dir[csv].sort.each do | file |
        puts file
        name = File.basename(file, ".csv")
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(name)
        i = 0
        CSV.foreach(file) do | row |
            worksheet.write_row(i, 0, row)
            i = i + 1
            count = count + 1
        end
    end

    workbook.close

    count
end

abort("Syntax: ruby -W0 csvtoxlsx.rb 'folder/*.csv' single.xlsx") if ARGV.length < 2

time_begin = Time.now
count = csvtoxls(ARGV[0], ARGV[1])
time_spent = Time.now - time_begin

puts "csvtoxlsx process #{ARGV[0]} with #{count} rows in #{time_spent.round(2)} seconds"
```